# Parallelise csv exports with oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am following this article: [How to unload table data to csv file - fastest way for millions of records](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536328100346697722), and cannot get either of the chunks related to the answer to work.

For example,

```
set term off
set feed off
set sqlformat csv
spool out.csv
select /*+ parallel */* from my_table;
spool off
```

Will return a csv file with zero rows.

Whereas:

```
create or replace procedure csv_unload ( 
  start_id my_table.x%type, end_id my_table.x%type
) as
  type t_tab is table of t%rowtype;
  rws  t_tab;
  output   utl_file.file_type;
  filename varchar2(100);
begin

  select * 
  bulk   collect into rws
  from   my_table
  where  x between start_id and end_id;
  
  filename := 't_' || start_id || '_' || end_id || '.csv';
  
  execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''YYYY/MM/DD'''; 
  
  output := utl_file.fopen ( 'TMP', filename, 'w' );
  
  utl_file.put ( output, 'X,Y' );
  
  for i in 1 .. rws.count loop
    utl_file.put_line ( output, rws(i).x || ',' || rws(i).y );
  end loop;
  
  utl_file.fclose ( output );
  
end csv_unload;
/
```

Throws the following error:

> Error(1,12): PLS-00201: identifier 'my_table' must be declared

How to appropriately use my_table correctly in these queries?

Comment: Do you have table named `my_table` in schema you're currently connected to?

Comment: @Littlefoot yes I do, also I found the solution to the first code chunk. I had to run this with script runner pressing the f5 key, and it now saves the table values. However, it's all processed sequentially, so it's still rather slow.